# PHP echo tag and quotes

Tags: php, echo, delimiter

I tried search a solution but I don't know how to do it.
On php when you use (echo) tag, it's possible use an other delimiter other than " or ' ?
For example, can I do this?

```
echo *Hello world*;
```

or

```
echo |Hello world|;
```

Maybe editting the php.ini?

Thanks you.

Comment: No.  Only quotes or `heredoc` or `nowdoc`. http://php.net/language.types.string

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why you want to do this. So I'm going to wait for that to come to light. I'm curious now.

Comment: because when I use echo tag and I need add names that contains (') or (") it break my head

Comment: So escape them: `\"` and `\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't do this. You would be changing the fundamentals of the language. It's like asking if you can use a `:` instead of a `;` to end statements.

If you need you use `'` in an echo statement you use `\`, which is the escape character for strings. For instance:

```
echo "Pete\'s coffee"
//prints: Pete's coffee
```

Comment: Bad news ... but thanks all for your rapid answer. I wasn't sure it was possible or not

Comment: @Simpleacc the good news is that there are ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Ya, I just saw it. I will use this method